# How do I determine which MySQL database my installation of Expression Engine is actually using?

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I have an existing installation of Expression Engine version 6 and I am trying to determine which MySQL database it is pointing to. I have several databases and the row counts for the table exp_channel_titles varies, and all are different than the number of rows returned when looking at that table through the expression engine control panel. I would like to confirm which db the system is actually configured to use.

Thanks

Bill

Answer (score 0):

you best look in the config file: /system/user/config/config.php

```
 array (
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'my_database',
    'username' => 'my_username',
    'password' => 'my_password',
```

Comment: Thanks! I poked around for a while but was not exactly sure where the config was. All set!